# WinServer 2008 R2 - ASP.NET Application not working when Server date is changed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, web-applications, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I migrated my ASP.NET Web Application from WinServer 2012 to WinServer 2008 R2 because it was the only server I had available at the time.

The WinServer2008 has installed IIS 6.1(build 7600) and SQL Server 2008 R2.

When the users connect to the server, the Web Application works completely right. However, they need to use a past date in order to insert the historical records. Also the Web Application is designed to operate with the system date to generate the appropiate monthly fees and taxes.

The problem appears when the date is changed to 2010. The controls misbehave, dropdownlist don't do their databind, the buttons are not working and registers are not inserted. But when I change the date to 2014 the WebApp works like a champ.

I think code is right, because of the well behave when date is near today. So I believe is an issue of Windows Server 2008 R2 or/and IIS 6.1

By the way, I have not installed Visual Studio on the server, so I can't do some code debugging.

Comment: Try to clear the browser cache. You  may have cached content from before the date was changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to Restart IIS and the SQL Services on each time I changed the date on the server and the inconvenient was overcome. 
Now the dropdownlists do the Databind, but there is an issue related to date formats.
**EDIT:**
I was able to solve my Language issues following this website lines
[Solving SQL-Server language issues](http://blackslot.com/blog/lenguaje-de-sql-server-dateformat/)